# Are multiple clock domains common in modern processors?

Tags: cpu-architecture, multicore

I am reading Euiseong Seo et al.'s "[Energy Efficient Scheduling of Real-Time Tasks on Multicore Processors](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4553699/)" (2008, doi: 10.1109/TPDS.2008.104, [PDF](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/dcea/cf26e85e7c8ff9b2da689a484a360f7015a3.pdf)). At a certain point they state that multicore architectures with a single clock domain are most common. Is this still the case?

Comment: Although not terribly important, still better to cite the paper as well.

Comment: In Intel i7, all the cores seem to operate at the same frequency, So I'd say Yes. http://www.intel.me/content/www/xr/en/processors/core/core-i7-processor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern processors (and SoCs) often have multiple clock domains. E.g., AMD's Phenom (2007) "[will allow individual cores to request different clock speeds](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2658/2)", IBM's POWER7 (2010) provided a digital phase-locked loop per core slice (Charles R. Lefurgy et al., "Active Management of Timing Guardband to Save Energy in POWER7", Figure 1, [PDF](https://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-lefurgy/micro44_Charles_Lefurgy.pdf)), SPARC T3 had "[Six clock and four voltage domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC_T3)" (Wikipedia is quoting Jinuk Luke Shin et al.'s "[A 40nm 16-core 128-thread CMT SPARC SoC processor](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5434030/)"; this does not provide per-core clock control), Intel's Silvermont provides a PLL per module (pair of cores sharing an L2 [see David Kanter's "[Silvermont, Intel’s Low Power Architecture](http://www.realworldtech.com/silvermont/8/)"). A quick-ish search seems to indicate that mainstream Intel processors do not support different frequencies for different cores, though they implement different clock domains (e.g., L3 cache and ring interconnect and cores having separate clocks, allowing the L3 to be snooped (e.g., by the GPU) at full speed without forcing the cores to go to full speed).

With heterogeneous multicore (e.g., ARM's big.LITTLE), different clock domains is almost a requirement if different cores are expect to operate at the same time (different core microarchitectures will typically have different frequency ranges).